# Using Javascript to change target div id in link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

So I'm using Rails and nested_form, and I have the following `link_to_add` code:

```
<%= f.link_to_add :exptypes, id:"addTab", :data => { :target => "#exptype_new_3" } do %>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add an Experimental Type

                <script> 
                  $('#addTab').click(function() {
                    add_tab('exptype');
                  })
                </script>
            <% end %>
```

The page source looks like this:

```
<li role="presentation">
            <a class="add_nested_fields" data-association="exptypes" data-blueprint-id="exptypes_fields_blueprint" data-target="#exptype_new_3" href="javascript:void(0)" id="addTab">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add an Experimental Type

                <script> 
                  $('#addTab').click(function() {
                    add_tab('exptype');
                  })
                </script>
</a>          </li>
```

Is there a way inside the Javacript `add_tab` function to change the `:target => "#exptype_new_3"` to something else?

I'm trying to get it so the div is incremented everytime a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

```
 $('#addTab').data('target', 'newTarget');
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/data/